# How to add a extjs button in a column in the grid to show another window?

Tags: javascript, extjs, datagridview, grid

I have have a column with the results of the search, but i need to show some informations added inside the result after i click in a button, but how i can do it?
I need to create a button to show, someone can help me?

tks.
Rodrigo.

Comment: Post your grid's code or some of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an action column for this:

```
{
    xtype:'actioncolumn',
    width:50,
    items: [{
        icon: 'extjs-build/examples/shared/icons/fam/cog_edit.png',  // Use a URL in the icon config
        tooltip: 'Edit',
        handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
            var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
            alert("Edit " + rec.get('firstname'));
        }
    },{
        icon: 'extjs-build/examples/restful/images/delete.png',
        tooltip: 'Delete',
        handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
            var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
            alert("Terminate " + rec.get('firstname'));
        }
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is ActionColumn (not hard to find on Google btw ...) :

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Action